# List View - Hightlight selected Item with paging- Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net

I have a list view with button control in one first column. When I click on the  button control, I'm able to see the selected row getting highlighted. Where as when I navigate to 2 or nth page of the list view and click on the button,I'm not getting my row selected or basically getting highlighted.

Appreciate any help.

Thanks